# PHP logic "and" "&&" for WordPress site restriction

Tags: php, wordpress, logic

I have two different user roles on my Website: Employer and Candidate. Every one had a type of profile but the profile from Candidate should see only employers and nobody else.

So I want a restriction in Wordpress like:

Employer CAN see Candidate
Candidate CAN'T see other Candidate
Candidate CAN see own Profile

**This is controlled by a plugin but it seems to be broken BECAUSE:**

Employer CAN see Candidate
Candidate CAN see other Candidate
Candidate CAN'T see own Profile

In the .php file from candidate profile is this code:

```
<?php
    if (!$show_candidate_public_profile) {
        if ($candidate->get_public_account() || get_current_user_id() == $candidate->get_author_id()) {
            $check = 1;
        } else {
            $check = 2;
        }
    } else {
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            if ($show_candidate_public_profile == 2 && get_current_user_id() == $candidate->get_author_id()) {
                if ($user->is_employer() && $candidate->get_public_account()) {
                    $check = 3;
                } else {
                    $check = 4;
                }
            } else {
                if ($candidate->get_public_account() || get_current_user_id() == $candidate->get_author_id()) {
                    $check = 1;
                } else {
                    $check = 2;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $check = 0;
        }
    }
```

**and the code for results right after code from above:**

```
     if (!$check) {
        ?>
        <div class="iwj-alert-box">
            <div class="container">
                <span>
                    <?php echo sprintf(__('You must be logged in to view this page. <a href="%s">Login here</a>', 'iwjob'), add_query_arg('redirect_to', $candidate->permalink(), $login_page_id)); ?>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    } else {
        if ($check == 2) {
            ?>
            <div class="iwj-alert-box">
                <div class="container">
                    <span>
                        <?php echo esc_html__('This profile is not public now.', 'iwjob'); ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } elseif ($check == 4) {
            ?>
            <div class="iwj-alert-box">
                <div class="container">
                    <span>
                        <?php echo esc_html__('This profile is not public or only employers can see.', 'iwjob'); ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } else {
            ?>
            <div class="iw-parallax" data-iw-paraspeed="0.1" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url($cover_image_url); ?>');"></div>
            <div class="iw-parallax-overlay"></div>
            <div class="content-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="info-top">
                        <div class="candidate-logo">
```

The check 3 is the only one check showing profile.

I tried to change the "&&" "||" "==" but i can't figure it out how this logic work.

So much php is too much for me. I have asked the Plugin creator but I am always waiting 5 days to reply and I need it now.

I would be very happy if someone would help me with this.

Thank you very much!

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work according to the behavior you have described(of course it will depend on the good functionality of your plugin). I had to take off some conditions since I don't know what they are and also you didn't provide further details, if you need them you have to add later, but this is quite simple and this code is much more readable.

First portion:

```
<?php
if(!is_user_logged_in())
    $check=false; //if user is not logged in check is false
else
{
    //check if user is employer or if is the profile owner
    if ($user->is_employer() || get_current_user_id() == $candidate->get_author_id())
        $check = 1; //sets 1 if allowed
    else
        $check = 2; //sets 2 if denied 
}
?>
```

Second portion:

```
if (!$check) //is check false? then show login message 
{
?>
    <div class="iwj-alert-box">
        <div class="container">
            <span>
                <?php echo sprintf(__('You must be logged in to view this page. <a href="%s">Login here</a>', 'iwjob'), add_query_arg('redirect_to', $candidate->permalink(), $login_page_id)); ?>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php
} 
else //check it's not false, so do more tests
{
    if ($check == 2) //if equals 2 then shows access denied message 
    {
?>
        <div class="iwj-alert-box">
            <div class="container">
                <span>
                    <?php echo esc_html__('This profile is not public now or only employers can see.', 'iwjob'); ?>
                 </span>
             </div>
        </div>
<?php 
     }
     elseif($check == 1) //user is profile owner or is an employer, show everything
     {
?>
            <div class="iw-parallax" data-iw-paraspeed="0.1" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url($cover_image_url); ?>');"></div>
            <div class="iw-parallax-overlay"></div>
            <div class="content-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="info-top">
                        <div class="candidate-logo">
```

If you want more tests, like about profile being public or not, you really have to provide more information. I hope it can help you.

Comment: First, thank you very much for helping. It isn't working with your code but I hope it will help me understand the php code from that plugin. I will try merge your and plugin code maybe it will work one day :D

Comment: Actually it's working! You are a hero!! There is a "?>" with is end of php but it should continue. I deleted it and now it WORKS!!! :) THANK YOU

Comment: Since it works, can you please mark this question as correct? This can help other people who is having similar doubt.